# Duplicate item returned from collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Blog Schema:

```js
{
        body: { type: String, required: true },
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        published: { type: String, default: false },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BlogUser' },
        comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comments' }],
        likes:[{user:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BlogUser' }}]
    }
```

Like Route for adding a like:

```
exports.likeBlog = async (req, res) => {
  const blog_id = req.params.blog_id;
  const user_id = req.body.user_id;
  await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(
    blog_id,
    {
      $push: {
        likes: {
          user: user_id,
        },
      },
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, newBlog) => {
      if (err) res.status(422).json(err);
      console.log(newBlog);
      res.json(newBlog);
    }
  );
};
```

Blog Route for reciveing a blog:

```js
exports.getBlogByID = async (req, res) => {
  const blog_id = req.params.blog_id;
  try {
    const blog = await Blog.findById(blog_id)
      .populate("comments")
      .populate("user");
    console.log(blog);
    res.json(blog);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json(error);
  }
};
```

When I add a like by calling `Like route` from client, I get a blog with correct amount of likes i.e only 1. But when I request blog from  `Blog Route` it returns me with two objects inside "likes" array, with both same as each other(same id too). Why am I getting such result? Mind you that I call 'Blog Route' after calling 'Like Route'.

Comment: you are doing a $push, so theorically you could have more than two same user. As many times as he likes the same blog.

Comment: yeah, I but I pushed a like item for one time only. I disable like option after adding a like from client side. @grodzi

Comment: 1. never trust your client. 2. check how many times you called likeBlog then. I hint that either your client is actually calling you twice (even though you think he prevents that), or you are calling the function twice, on the OPTION verb e.g

Comment: @grodzi So there's no problem from server side right? Also I am calling likeBlog one time only, at least that's what I think I am doing. Should I replace the above code to client side code?

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine after I changed "like route" to this:

```js
exports.likeBlog = async (req, res) => {
  const blog_id = req.params.blog_id;
  const user_id = req.body.user_id;
  const blog = await Blog.findById(blog_id);
  blog.likes.unshift({ user: user_id });
  await blog.save();
  Blog.findById(blog_id)
    .then((result) => {
      res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(501).json({ error });
    });
};
```

I still don't know what's the difference between the two though.

Comment: unshift removes the first elem of your array (independantly from what you give him {user: 1}, null or {user: user_id}). You are **not** fixing the fact that you are likely to do **two** updates: one which adds a user, and one which removesit and adds it again.
This will fail when you add an other user (the first one will be unliked and likely the second user will be listed twice ...)

Comment: Just tried with 3 different users and it's working fine like it should. And unshit doesn't remove the first elem of array, it actually adds the new element at the beginning .@grodzi

Comment: whoops you are right for unshift @yash Boura . I don't understand why you are not pushing instead but if it works for you so be it. The find + write feels pretty sad though. If it were me I would just store a Mixed (id: 1) and simply update. I would not even return the blog but you have your constraints